# Disable smart identification globally, also for BPT components?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

To simplify (and stabilize) test development, I turn off smart identification when creating tests. I do this by disabling smart identification globally in the test's settings dialog box.

As far as I can see, there is no way to achieve the same for business process tests in UFT -- there is no settings dialog for BPTs. For BPT components, there is one, but it does not contain the config item to disable smart identification.

```
CreateObject("QuickTest.Application").BusinessComponent.Settings.Run.DisableSmartIdentification = True
```

will indeed disable smart identification for the current business component in the current run, but no matter if (or when) I save the component, the setting will be set back to false after re-opening the component.

**So how do I disable smart identification for business components?**

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only known way to achieve the target is to put

```
CreateObject("QuickTest.Application").BusinessComponent.Settings.Run.DisableSmartIdentification = True
```

into a library's init code, and to associate the library with the component(s) (via an application area) so it is executed when the component is about to be executed. This will then happen both for standalone test and standalone component execution.

To differentiate between both, one could query `CreateObject ("QuickTest.Application").CurrentDocumentType`, also see [Can I determine whether current component is executed from ALM's test lab, or interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068840/can-i-determine-whether-current-component-is-executed-from-alms-test-lab-or-in).