# Can I determine whether current component is executed from ALM's test lab, or interactively?

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center

**Can I determine (programmatically) how my current business component scriptcode has been initiated?**

It could be

- standalone (using "Run" from UFT's toolbar while the component is open)
- from a standalone test execution (using "Run" from UFT's toolbar while a test calling the component is open)
- from a test lab execution (using "Run" or "Run all" button in the test set im ALM)?

Foggily related: [Can I determine if current test execs from test lab or interactively from within QTP IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157054/can-i-determine-if-current-test-execs-from-test-lab-or-interactively-from-within)

Comment: Why you always get strange requirement...? LOL

Comment: I am building frameworks, and such strange questions show up easily if you want to support debugging with special features...

Comment: Can you shade some light on what kind of debugging feature you want to add?

Comment: Well, when running for a real test, I want to source the test data by adressing it through the test set, while during interactive execution, I want to use an alternative adressing schema, all withoutany  code or config change.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. Hope I could help, but I have never tried this before. May be @Motti can help you.

Comment: In practice, one usually has a BPT to develop. Executing a component alone is more of an exception, so i am not exactly stuck.

Comment: @ManishChristian, sorry I don't know *everything* :)

Comment: @Motti Oh sure you do, and you KNOW it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component is executed standalone, `CreateObject ("QuickTest.Application").CurrentDocumentType` returns `"Business component"`.

If the component is executed from within a BPT (no matter if the BPT is executed interactively, or from within a test set) `CurrentDocumentType` returns `"Test"`.

Combined with the setting brought to light in the related question (and answer), this answers the question. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing.